# Every time I de-activate a custom plugin, the site encounters a critical error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a custom plugin that I no longer use. I was looking to de-activate it from my site (and, subsequently, my network) but every time I attempt to, I get this error:

> Please activate the {plugin name} plugin

with no further output from WordPress (it's just the text and nothing else!) I'm effectively locked out of everything on the web end with no options but to restore the DB to an earlier version.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this before?

Comment: As you can see from a cross core files [search on the GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/search?q=%22Please+activate+the%22&type=Code) repo, there's no such native string. That's effectively the custom plugin you're using, or some plugin that depends on it. Use SFTP to get access to your server and show us the code of the custom plugin. But generally speaking: This is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom plugin is probably directly integrated into your theme or some other plugin. The developer must have added this notice to prevent you from deactivating by mistake the plugin and making your site behave in an unexpected way, this is not a notice issued from wordpress itself.

You need someone to look into your plugins and theme code, check where this notice originates, and remove the dependencies.

Comment: You were right - it just so happens that another custom plugin was using `is_plugin_active()` to ensure that the dependency (the other plugin) was still activated.